# How can I update a single field from the results of a select with a join

Tags: join, select

I wish to change a flag from Y to N. I have been given a select which gives me two records for which I would like to change the value. 
As a newbie to anything more advanced than the basics, I am totally at a loss.

As this is a live table, I would am too cautious to attempt this without fully understanding that I will update the correct records.

```
SELECT a.*, '||' , b.* FROM basecode b, type t
WHERE b.b_id IN ('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
AND b.btype_id = t.ttype_id
```

The resultant code gives me records with multiple fields, but I just wish to change just a couple of records flag fields from 'Y' to 'N'

Stripping away the other fields I have

iflag='Y'
oflag='Y'

And just want them to be set to 'N' from the previous select.